# Firebase Errors don't show up on live server but do on localhost

Tags: javascript, firebase, localhost

I get the following errors when running my firebase server using local host or deploying it (Firebase serve or firebase deploy commands)

> GET
> http://localhost:5000/Issue-Tracker/public/Bug-Tracker/CSS/snackBar.css
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) index.html:94          GET
> http://localhost:5000/public/Bug-Tracker/JS/firebase.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:114 Uncaught
> FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created
>
> - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
>   at f (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:114:27)
>   at Object.i [as auth] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:196:31)
>   at app.js:26:23

However, when I use a live server like here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer
I do not get these errors and my program works. I am confused. Why is this so?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you are comparing behaviour of the raw and compiled (run through Webpack/TypeScript's compiler) versions of your project. Are you using TypeScript or raw JavaScript? Which version of the Firebase Library are you using? Is this a site to be hosted on Firebase Hosting or deployed to Cloud Functions using express?

Comment: @samthecodingman Yes, I'm comparing behaviour. I am using raw JavaScript. I am using version 11.0.0 of Firebase. I am building the website locally, and just using firebase deploy to have a live link to share. I don't think I have used express.